# fully stretch text horizontally on page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, text-manipulation, letterspacing

Is there a way to fully stretch one line of text on the full width of the page, without manually setting the letter spacing, no matter how many characters on the line?

Comment: If it is just one line, adding `\hfill` between each word should produce the output you desire..

Comment: I did not really make that clear, sorry  for that, but I am looking for a method that solves this by letter-spacing, not word-spacing. See my comment below

Comment: look at  the letterspacing tag: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letterspacing

Comment: tnx, I am aware of that. However, this gives less flexibility in the sense you have to constantly alter the letter-spacing relative to the amount of characters, font, font-size, font-type and width of page. The examples below are quite close to what I want, however, they distribute on word-spacing

Comment: @Mixhael You could make your intent clearer; letterspacing is generally *not* a good typographical device for getting justified text.

Comment: Tnx @egreg, I'm sure it's not. The intent is to copy the design which was delivered to me in .ai (adobe illustrator) format. It concerns a footer of a letterhead with contact and personal information, which -for the purpose of graphical design- is stretched allover the page.

Comment: The soul package referenced in some of the letterspacing tagged answers provides thus feature

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the spacing between words (or inter-word spacing) when you reference "a line text".

If the number of characters will always fit on the line, then the optional `s`-parameter for `\makebox` alignment inserts enough *inter-word* spacing stretch to fill the box. If the text is greater than the box width, an overfull `\hbox` warning is generated:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example.
\begin{document}
\makebox[\linewidth][s]{Here is some text.} \par
\makebox[\linewidth][s]{Here is some more text.} \par
\makebox[\linewidth][s]{Here is a whole whack of text, plus some punctuation.} \par
\makebox[\linewidth][s]{Here is a whole whack of text, plus some punctuation, and then some more text.} \par
\makebox[\linewidth][s]{Here is a whole whack of text, plus some punctuation, and then some more text, and nothing else.} \par
\end{document}​
```

The last line stretches beyond the text margin. In the above minimal working example (MWE), replacing `\linewidth` with `\textwidth` would also work.

---

For inter-letter spacing, the [`soul` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) can be of help. You define your own inter-letter, inner and outer spaces via a command `\sodef{<cmd>}{<font>}{<inter-letter>}{<inner space>}{<outer space>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}% http://ctan.org/pkg/soul
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example.
\begin{document}
\sodef\spaceout{}{0pt plus 1fil}{.4em plus 1fil}{0pt}
\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\spaceout{Here is some text.}} \par
\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\spaceout{Here is some more text.}} \par
\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\spaceout{Here is a whole whack of text, plus some punctuation.}} \par
\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\spaceout{Here is a whole whack of text, plus some punctuation, and then some more text.}} \par
\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\spaceout{Here is a whole whack of text, plus some punctuation, and then some more text, and nothing else.}} \par
\end{document}​
```

Since I am unfamiliar with this kind of modification, consider this just a guide to get you going. The [`soul` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf) (section **3 Letter spacing**, p 8 onward) is filled with examples.

I'm sure [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) would also be able to facilitate your needs.

Comment: Thanks all. This is exactly what I meant, however: I was looking for a method that spreads text evenly on a horizontal line by increasing the letter-space, instead of the word-space. Is that possible too?

Comment: So, 'exactly' was not the right wording. It is very close to what I want

Comment: Tnx @Werner, will look into the soul package

Answer (score 17):

`spread` as a command to a box instruction is built into tex (texbook, p.77):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hbox spread \linewidth{Here is some text.}
\end{document}
```

[image: text spread to line width]

Answer (score 11):

Using the `soul` package

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{soul}
\sodef\ugg{}{.4em plus 1fill}{1em plus 2 fill}{2em plus 2fill minus.1em}

\begin{document}


\noindent\ugg{one two three\\four five six}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

if you want to stretch all the letters evenly rather than words you can use:

```
\makeatletter
\def\spreadeven#1{%
\@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
  \next\hfill
 }%
}

\spreadeven{A fox jumped over the lazy dog}
\madeatother
```

This uses the LaTeX kernel `@tfor` to iterate over all the letters and add `hfill` between them.

Comment: Thanks for that. It almost does it as I wanted it, however it seems not to take spaces into consideration, so spaces won't be doubled. I can't differentiate between words anymore

Comment: @Mixhael I answered this way based on your comments in Werner's answer. i think what you are looking is `\so{}` using the `soul` package.

Answer (score 7):

In ConTeXt there is the `\stretched` macro for this purpose. Example:

```
\starttext
    \stretched{Here is some text}
\stoptext
```

[image: result]