# right alignment of spaced out letters not matching

Tags: horizontal-alignment

## The letters aren't right aligned perfectly

I am trying to create a logo where the letters are both left and flush right, but some of the letters are not correctly right aligned. I have been using the solutions suggested here [fully stretch text horizontally on page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/fully-stretch-text-horizontally-on-page) but the "G" and the "T" clearly do not right align. How can this be remedied? From my MWE

### Almost

[image]

### Closer, but no longer filling the linewidth

[image]

## MWE

In the below I have some text on the right with `\vspace{0em}` so the two are top aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{ugq}
\usepackage{soul}
\sodef\spaceout{}{0pt plus 1fil}{.4em plus 1fil}{0pt}
\sodef\ugg{}{.4em plus 1fill}{1em plus 2 fill}{2em plus 2fill minus.1em}
\makeatletter
\def\spreadeven#1{%
\@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
\next\hfill
}%
}
\begin{document}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\vspace{0mm}
\textsf{\textbf{\fontsize{35}{45}\selectfont %
\fontsize{25}{55}\selectfont
\spreadeven{ENDSING}\\
\spreadeven{ENDSINT}\\
}}
\end{minipage}%
}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\vspace{0mm}
Some other text \\
goes here \\
hence the \\
\texttt{vspace\{0em\}}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \\

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\vspace{0mm}
\textsf{\textbf{\fontsize{35}{45}\selectfont %
\fontsize{25}{55}\selectfont
\spaceout{ENDSING}\\
\spaceout{ENDSINT}\\
}}
\end{minipage}%
}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\vspace{0mm}
Some other text \\
goes here \\
hence the \\
\texttt{vspace\{0em\}}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \\

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\vspace{0mm}
\textsf{\textbf{\fontsize{35}{45}\selectfont %
\fontsize{25}{55}\selectfont
\ugg{ENDSING}\\
\ugg{ENDSINT}\\
}}
\end{minipage}%
}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\vspace{0mm}
Some other text \\
goes here \\
hence the \\
\texttt{vspace\{0em\}}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \\
\end{document}
```

## Changing font sizes

In the final result I will likely also set the second line to use a smaller font, so the solution should hopefully work with a mix of font sizes, albeit where the font size on each line is the same.

Comment: There is no automatic solution.  You will have to use some negative space (or protrusion with microtype) and the value will have to tried out.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Glyph design. They can have varying side bearings.