# Generate PDF and text with single tex file

Tags: macros, text

How can I generate both PDF **and** text version with a single `.tex` file? Text version requirements documented below.

## Input

For example, given this `.tex` file ([texlive.net PDF generator online](https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%5B11pt,a4paper%5D%7Barticle%7D%0A%0A%25%20I%20doubt%20this%20will%20affect%20the%20PDF%20to%20text%20solution,%0A%25%20but%20I%27ve%20included%20it%20to%20make%20it%20as%20similar%20as%20possible%20to%20my%20real%20document.%0A%5Cusepackage%5B%0A%09paperheight=11.00in,%0A%09paperwidth=8.50in,%0A%09margin=1.00in,%0A%09top=1.00in,%0A%09left=1.00in,%0A%09bottom=1.00in%0A%5D%7Bgeometry%7D%0A%0A%5Cusepackage%5Bhidelinks%5D%7Bhyperref%7D%0A%0A%25%20This%20part%20is%20%5Cinput%20from%20another%20file.%0A%25%20Included%20inline%20for%20your%20convenience.%0A%5Chypersetup%7B%0A%09pdfinfo=%7B%0A%09%09Author=%7Btfstwbbnb%7D,%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%5Cnewcommand%7B%5CauthorName%7D%7Btfstwbbnb%7D%0A%0A%25%20xelatex%20required,%20pdflatex%20does%20not%20work%0A%25%20%5Csetmainfont%7BUbuntu%20Light%7D%5B%0A%25%20%09ItalicFont=Ubuntu%20Light%20Italic,%0A%25%20%09BoldFont=Ubuntu,%0A%25%20%09BoldItalicFont=Ubuntu%20Italic,%0A%25%20%5D%0A%0A%5Csetlength%5Cparindent%7B0pt%7D%0A%5Cpagenumbering%7Bgobble%7D%0A%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bxcolor%7D%0A%5Cnewcommand%7B%5Cgray%7D%5B1%5D%7B%5Ctextcolor%7Bgray%7D%7B%231%7D%7D%0A%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bsetspace%7D%0A%5Csetstretch%7B1.10%7D%0A%0A%25%20https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50510%0A%5Cnewcommand%7B%5Cfitline%7D%5B1%5D%7B%5Cmakebox%5B%5Clinewidth%5D%5Bs%5D%7B%231%7D%7D%0A%0A%5Cnewcommand%7B%5CmyInnerSpacing%7D%7B0.40%5Cbaselineskip%7D%0A%0A%5Chypersetup%7B%0A%09pdfinfo=%7B%0A%09%09Title=%7Btfstwbbnb%20demo%7D,%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%5Cnewcommand%7B%5CoptionalOne%7D%7BoptionalOne%7D%0A%5Cnewcommand%7B%5CoptionalTwo%7D%7BoptionalTwo%7D%0A%25%20Links%20should%20appear%20as%20link%20text%20(%22requiredOne%22)%20in%20text%20version.%0A%5Cnewcommand%7B%5CrequiredOne%7D%7B%5Chref%7Bmailto:invalid@example.com%7D%7BrequiredOne%7D%7D%0A%5Cnewcommand%7B%5CrequiredTwo%7D%7BrequiredTwo%7D%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%09%25%20Alignment%20in%20text%20version%20does%20not%20matter%20to%20me.%20Can%20be%20left-justified%20or%20centered.%0A%09%5Cbegin%7Bcenter%7D%0A%09%5CLARGE%7B%5Ctextbf%7BTitle%7D%7D%0A%09%5Cend%7Bcenter%7D%0A%0A%09%5Cvspace%7B%5CmyInnerSpacing%7D%0A%0A%09%5CoptionalOne%20%5C%5C%0A%09%25%20Optionals%20might%20be%20commented%20out%20like%20so:%0A%09%25%20%5CoptionalTwo%20%5C%5C%0A%09%5CrequiredOne%20%5C%5C%0A%09%5Cgray%7B%5CrequiredTwo%7D%20%5C%5C%0A%0A%09%5Cvspace%7B%5CmyInnerSpacing%7D%0A%0A%09%25%20Text%20formmatting%20should%20be%20stripped%20in%20text%20version.%0A%09%5Ctextbf%7BLorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%7D,%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit,%20sed%20do%20eiusmod%20tempor%20incididunt%20ut%20labore%20et%20dolore%20magna%20aliqua.%20%5C%5C%0A%0A%09Purus%20semper%20eget%20duis%20at%20tellus%20at.%20Tellus%20cras%20adipiscing%20enim%20eu%20turpis%20egestas%20pretium%20aenean.%20%5C%5C%0A%0A%09Felis%20donec,%20%5C%5C%0A%09tfstwbbnb%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D)):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

% I doubt this will affect the PDF to text solution,
% but I've included it to make it as similar as possible to my real document.
\usepackage[
    paperheight=11.00in,
    paperwidth=8.50in,
    margin=1.00in,
    top=1.00in,
    left=1.00in,
    bottom=1.00in
]{geometry}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% This part is \input from another file.
% Included inline for your convenience.
\hypersetup{
    pdfinfo={
        Author={tfstwbbnb},
    }
}

\newcommand{\authorName}{tfstwbbnb}

% xelatex required, pdflatex does not work
% \setmainfont{Ubuntu Light}[
%   ItalicFont=Ubuntu Light Italic,
%   BoldFont=Ubuntu,
%   BoldItalicFont=Ubuntu Italic,
% ]

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\gray}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.10}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50510
\newcommand{\fitline}[1]{\makebox[\linewidth][s]{#1}}

\newcommand{\myInnerSpacing}{0.40\baselineskip}

\hypersetup{
    pdfinfo={
        Title={tfstwbbnb demo},
    }
}

\newcommand{\optionalOne}{optionalOne}
\newcommand{\optionalTwo}{optionalTwo}
% Links should appear as link text ("requiredOne") in text version.
\newcommand{\requiredOne}{\href{mailto:invalid@example.com}{requiredOne}}
\newcommand{\requiredTwo}{requiredTwo}

\begin{document}
    % Alignment in text version does not matter to me. Can be left-justified or centered.
    \begin{center}
    \LARGE{\textbf{Title}}
    \end{center}

    \vspace{\myInnerSpacing}

    \optionalOne \\
    % Optionals might be commented out like so:
    % \optionalTwo \\
    \requiredOne \\
    \gray{\requiredTwo} \\

    \vspace{\myInnerSpacing}

    % Text formmatting should be stripped in text version.
    \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \\

    Purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean. \\

    Felis donec, \\
    tfstwbbnb
\end{document}
```

[image: input]

## Expected

How can I have it output (as plain text):

```
Title

optionalOne
requiredOne
requiredTwo

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean.

Felis donec,
tfstwbbnb
```

## Copy and Paste

Opening up the PDF in a viewer and copy/paste gives:

```
TitleoptionalOnerequiredOnerequiredTwoLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt utlabore et dolore magna aliqua.Purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean.Felis donec,tfstwbbnb
```

## `pdftotext`

`pdftotext` gives better results, but still not as I want (missing newlines, too many newlines, extra `0x0c` character at end):

```
Title
optionalOne
requiredOne
requiredTwo
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean.
Felis donec,
tfstwbbnb
```

## PDF to text summary

Essentially, the plaintext output should be:

- All coloring (`\textcolor{...}`) ignored
- All font sizing (`\LARGE`, `\small`) ignored
- All links (`requiredOne`) displayed as text
- All explicit newlines kept (for example, between the `optionalOne` and `requiredOne`)
- All paragraphs kept (for example, between the `Lorem ipsum ...` and `Purus semper ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add visible paragraph breaks, then remove:

```
pdflatex '\AddToHook{para/after}{\hbox{PARA}}\input'  cc873
pdftotext cc873.pdf
sed -i -e 's/^PARA//' -e 's/[\f]//' cc873.txt
cat cc873.txt
```

Produces

```
Title

optionalOne
requiredOne
requiredTwo

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean.

Felis donec,
tfstwbbnb
```

(You could remove trailing blank lines with sed as well if they are an issue, I just remove the ^L here.

Comment: Your result definitely looks much better than mine, however, there is still an extra newline after "ut" in the first paragraph. Is there a way to fix this too? I'm assuming it would be `AddToHook{something}`, but I don't know where to look for that "something".

Comment: Found https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf#page=4, but no hook names.

Comment: @tfstwbbnb `texdoc ltpara-doc`

Comment: @tfstwbbnb you could redefine `\\ ` to be say `EOL\newline`  although it's harder than it should be due to the mis-used `\\ ` in the source which are an error `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 76--77`

Comment: Can you expand on how redefining `\\ ` to `EOL\newline` would help with the "ut" in the middle of a paragraph being split with a newline? Anyway, this particular problem can be solved with `paperwidth=1000in`. I will accept your solution shortly.

Comment: @tfstwbbnb actually I misread your comment

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc gets it almost right:

`pandoc yourfile.tex -f latex -t plain -o yourfile.txt --wrap=none`

results in

```
Title

optionalOne
requiredOne
requiredTwo

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean.
Felis donec,
tfstwbbnb
```

The only issue is the empty lines between the Lorem ipsum sentences. However, the combination of `\\` followed by an empty line is not very clean LaTeX, I understand that Pandoc refuses to convert that :)

If instead empty lines between paragraphs are created with `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` and without any `\\` at the end of a paragraph then Pandoc converts the empty lines perfectly. LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

% I doubt this will affect the PDF to text solution,
% but I've included it to make it as similar as possible to my real document.
\usepackage[
    paperheight=11.00in,
    paperwidth=8.50in,
    margin=1.00in,
    top=1.00in,
    left=1.00in,
    bottom=1.00in
]{geometry}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

% This part is \input from another file.
% Included inline for your convenience.
\hypersetup{
    pdfinfo={
        Author={tfstwbbnb},
    }
}

\newcommand{\authorName}{tfstwbbnb}

% xelatex required, pdflatex does not work
% \setmainfont{Ubuntu Light}[
%   ItalicFont=Ubuntu Light Italic,
%   BoldFont=Ubuntu,
%   BoldItalicFont=Ubuntu Italic,
% ]

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\gray}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.10}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50510
\newcommand{\fitline}[1]{\makebox[\linewidth][s]{#1}}

\newcommand{\myInnerSpacing}{0.40\baselineskip}

\hypersetup{
    pdfinfo={
        Title={tfstwbbnb demo},
    }
}

\newcommand{\optionalOne}{optionalOne}
\newcommand{\optionalTwo}{optionalTwo}
% Links should appear as link text ("requiredOne") in text version.
\newcommand{\requiredOne}{\href{mailto:invalid@example.com}{requiredOne}}
\newcommand{\requiredTwo}{requiredTwo}

\begin{document}
    % Alignment in text version does not matter to me. Can be left-justified or centered.
    \begin{center}
    \LARGE{\textbf{Title}}
    \end{center}

    \optionalOne \\
    % Optionals might be commented out like so:
    % \optionalTwo \\
    \requiredOne \\
    \gray{\requiredTwo}

    % Text formmatting should be stripped in text version.
    \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

    Purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean.

    Felis donec, \\
    tfstwbbnb
\end{document}
```

The pdf created from this code is almost the same as in the question, the difference being that the empty lines are a bit smaller. If you want the big gaps then use

```
\usepackage[skip=\baselineskip]{parskip}
```

instead.